# Java program not seeming to run code inside of while loop

Tags: java, while-loop

I am working on a program where I have two clients connect to each other using sockets. I have a while loop that forces the clients to wait until a successful connection has been made between each other before continuing, but the code inside of the loop does not seem to be running correctly.

I have tried putting print statements inside of the while loop, which causes the code to run how I expect, but when I remove them, it seems as though the while loop is no longer checking the condition that I have set, and thus keeps hanging up.

```java
boolean keepRunning = true;
while (keepRunning)
{
  if (alice.ready())
  {
    keepRunning = false;
  }
}
```

```java
public void ready()
{
  return (socket1 != null) && (socket2 != null);
}
```

The code should continue checking if the two clients are ready, and then continue on in the program, but currently with the code above, the clients connect to each other, but then never exit the loop, leading me to believe that the inner code is not being run quite how I am expecting. Again, when I put print statements inside of the main while loop, the code works how I expect.

Comment: I doubt it's related to your problem, but fast spinning loops like that are not a good practice. At least put a sleep statement in there.

Comment: I would add some kind of 'timer' to see how long you are waiting. If the timer never stops, then you may have a bigger problem with 'alice'. maybe 'alice' is never changing/updated??

Comment: @NightRider When I added print statements, I had it print the sockets that alice was waiting for, and WITH the print statements, the sockets changed and worked correctly (i.e. were not null), meaning alice progresses as intended.